# Python and specyfic xml praise file problem, cant get values form getchildren()

Tags: python, xml

i trying to write script which can change a values in xml file, but file has very diffucult construction. I need values to edit from xml row "r2dd" exactly : 10.0;10.0;26.0;14.0. By i cant assign them to a variable.

xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<objects fpmi.archive.type="components" framework.version="7.9.8.2018060714" fpmi.version="9.9.8.0" timestamp="Thu Sep 27 15:00:19 CEST 2018">
  <arraylist len="0"/>
<c cls="com.inductiveautomation.factorypmi.application.components.template.TemplateHolder">
  <c-comm>
    <p2df>26.0;14.0</p2df>
    <r2dd>10.0;10.0;26.0;14.0</r2dd>
    <str>X123_C61023</str>
    <lc>10.0;10.0;16;0;0.7058824;1.3333334</lc>
  </c-comm>
  <c-c m="setParameterValues" s="1;java.util.Map">
    <o cls="java.util.HashMap">
      <o-c m="put" s="2;O;O">
        <str>tagPath</str>
        <str>X123_X123_C61023</str>
      </o-c>
    </o>
  </c-c>
  <c-c m="setTemplatePath" s="1;str">
    <str>[network]premium/aw1/tags/monitors</str>
  </c-c>
</c>
```

this is my code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

mytree = ET.parse('sample.xml')
myroot = mytree.getroot()

for x in myroot.findall('c'):
    other=x.find('c-comm').getchildren()
    print('values : ', other)
    other_value=other.get('type')
    print(other_value)
```

Please Can someone help me to assign this values from "r2dd" xml rows to a variable ?
At this moment console shows only :

```
    other_value=other.get('type')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
values :  [<Element 'p2df' at 0x035753C0>, <Element 'r2dd' at 0x03575410>, <Element 'str' at 0x03575438>, <Element 'lc' at 0x03575488>]
```

but no values. please help

(I can got access to this elements only usning getchildren()... but this is a wrong way).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ElementTree find returns 'None'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60791069/elementtree-find-returns-none)

Answer (score 0):

I think is because you are not indexing the list that returns getchildren.

```
other=x.find('c-comm').getchildren()
print('values : ', other)
other_value=other.get('type')
```

As you can see in this part you store the list of children inside other and then you are treating this variable as a child. And can observe this in the print that you post:

```
values :  [<Element 'p2df' at 0x035753C0>, <Element 'r2dd' at 0x03575410>, <Element 'str' at 0x03575438>, <Element 'lc' at 0x03575488>]
```

So, you are looking for the second element of this list.