# ElementTree find returns 'None'?

Tags: python, parsing

I'm using ElementTree with Python to parse an XML file.

This is the sample of XML file I'm trying to parse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<objects fpmi.archive.type="components" framework.version="7.9.8.2018060714" fpmi.version="9.9.8.0" timestamp="Thu Sep 27 15:00:19 CEST 2018">
  <arraylist len="0"/>
<c cls="com.inductiveautomation.factorypmi.application.components.template.TemplateHolder">
  <c-comm>
    <p2df>26.0;14.0</p2df>
    <r2dd>10.0;10.0;26.0;14.0</r2dd>
    <str>X123_C61023</str>
    <lc>10.0;10.0;16;0;0.7058824;1.3333334</lc>
  </c-comm>
  <c-c m="setParameterValues" s="1;java.util.Map">
    <o cls="java.util.HashMap">
      <o-c m="put" s="2;O;O">
        <str>tagPath</str>
        <str>X123_X123_C61023</str>
      </o-c>
    </o>
  </c-c>
  <c-c m="setTemplatePath" s="1;str">
    <str>[network]premium/aw1/tags/monitors</str>
  </c-c>
</c>
```

console always return None .

My code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

mytree = ET.parse('sample.xml')
myroot = mytree.getroot()

for x in myroot.findall('c'):
        p2df=x.find('p2df')
        r2dd=x.find('r2dd')
        print(p2df, r2dd)
```

Please help..

Comment: Have you done any debugging? https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Element.findall()` searches only elements with a tag which are direct children of the current element. The same is happening with `find()` but `find()` returns the first match. So first you need to traverse to `c-comm`, to find the `p2df` element, and since `objects` is the root node, you first traverse to `c`, then `c-comm` to then find the objects. See below snippet.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

mytree = ET.parse('sample.xml')
myroot = mytree.getroot()

cNode = myroot.find('c')
for x in cNode.findall('c-comm'):
  p2df=x.find('p2df')
  r2dd=x.find('r2dd')
  print(p2df.text, r2dd.text)
```

Your example xml is not well formed. You need a closing `</objects>` tag at the end for the parser to be able to read the file.

Comment: thanks for help, but this method doesn't work. the console returns me nothing ...

Comment: Aha @thomas_cl, I see now that I missed that you were missing a closing  </objects> tag in your example, so objects is actually the root. I updated my code to fit that structure and it should work now.

Comment: thanks its working! could you look on my next anwser above i have a new problem

Comment: Hey, sorry but to keep things clean Stackoverflow does not allow follow up questions to carry on in the answers. Since my answer solved your initial problem, accept it and open a new question. I'd love to help but I'll do it when you open a new question.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for your help its working now.
but I did it in a different way also .:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

mytree = ET.parse('sample.xml')
myroot = mytree.getroot()

interface = myroot.getchildren()[1].getchildren()[0]
print(interface)

r2dd = interface.getchildren()[1]
print(r2dd.text)

str = interface.getchildren()[2]
print(str.text)
```

now i have a next problem how to add values for other items in this xml? i mean next items, this is file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<objects fpmi.archive.type="components" framework.version="7.9.8.2018060714" fpmi.version="9.9.8.0" timestamp="Thu Sep 27 15:00:19 CEST 2018">
  <arraylist len="0"/>
<c cls="com.inductiveautomation.factorypmi.application.components.template.TemplateHolder">
  <c-comm>
    <p2df>26.0;14.0</p2df>
    <r2dd>10.0;10.0;26.0;14.0</r2dd>
    <str>XXY_Y61021</str>
    <lc>10.0;10.0;16;0;0.7058824;1.3333334</lc>
  </c-comm>
  <c-c m="setParameterValues" s="1;java.util.Map">
    <o cls="java.util.HashMap">
      <o-c m="put" s="2;O;O">
        <str>tagPath</str>
        <str>XXY_Y6102_C61021</str>
      </o-c>
    </o>
  </c-c>
  <c-c m="setTemplatePath" s="1;str">
    <str>XXXYYYYY</str>
  </c-c>
</c>

<c cls="com.inductiveautomation.factorypmi.application.components.template.TemplateHolder">
  <c-comm>
    <p2df>26.0;14.0</p2df>
    <r2dd>60.0;10.0;26.0;14.0</r2dd>
    <str>XXY_Y61022</str>
    <lc>60.0;10.0;16;0;0.7058824;1.3333334</lc>
  </c-comm>
  <c-c m="setParameterValues" s="1;java.util.Map">
    <o cls="java.util.HashMap">
      <o-c m="put" s="2;O;O">
        <str>tagPath</str>
        <str>XXY_Y6102_C61022</str>
      </o-c>
    </o>
  </c-c>
  <c-c m="setTemplatePath" s="1;str">
    <str>XXXYYYYY</str>
  </c-c>
</c>

<c cls="com.inductiveautomation.factorypmi.application.components.template.TemplateHolder">
  <c-comm>
    <p2df>26.0;14.0</p2df>
    <r2dd>110.0;10.0;26.0;14.0</r2dd>
    <str>XXY_Y61021</str>
    <lc>110.0;10.0;16;0;0.7058824;1.3333334</lc>
  </c-comm>
  <c-c m="setParameterValues" s="1;java.util.Map">
    <o cls="java.util.HashMap">
      <o-c m="put" s="2;O;O">
        <str>tagPath</str>
        <str>XXY_Y6102_C61021</str>
      </o-c>
    </o>
  </c-c>
  <c-c m="setTemplatePath" s="1;str">
    <str>XXXYYYYY</str>
  </c-c>
</c>
```

yes this example has missing closure for object but on pc i have a full file